# Extract Substring from Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string that should look like this in java:
`String input = add entity <a-zA-Z>,<a-zA-z>`
Now I want to check, whether a given String has the right format or not. If so I want to get the handed words.

I already have the checking part

```
boolean foo(String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("add entity [a-zA-Z]*[,][a-zA-Z]*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

I have found several other questions here where they have solved a similar problem with

```
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

But if I do so the console always throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
```

Does anyone have an advice for me how to solve this ?
Thank you guys very much.

Comment: [`String.matches#`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method does the same thing. Since the pattern matches the whole string + there are no Capturing groups --> group[1] would be erroneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1`

This error is due to the fact that your regex pattern has no captured group #1.

You can change your pattern to this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("add entity ([a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z]*)");
```

so that part of `"add entity "` is captured in group #1. Note that there is no need to escape comma in a regex pattern.